# Play Framework Code Coverage

Tags: playframework, jacoco

Is there a way to obtain the test coverage when using Play Framework?

I am using Play Framework 2.6.12 and it's a Java project. I need to extract a report on coverage to use it with Sonarqube.

[Cobertura Test coverage](https://www.playframework.com/modules/cobertura-2.4/home) is apparently dead. I got [JaCoCo SBT](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco) working manually, but I need to change the report type to XML and I can't figure it out with the existing documentation (or lack thereof). Apparently the [JaCoCo SBT Repository](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco) is also inactive.

**Question:** Can anyone tell me how/where I can change the [settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-jacoco/settings.html) to make an XML Report or recommend another tool to get the Test Coverage with Play Framework?

**Example**
When I do this is build.sbt, I get an error.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, JacocoItPlugin)

Error: Cannot add dependency 'org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.7.9' to configuration 'it' of module XXX because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

**Config Example**

This is how I probably can change the report type to XML, but I don't know where I have to put this line of code. (Note `JacocoReportFormats.XML`):

```
JacocoReportSettings(
  "Jacoco Coverage Report",
  None,
  JacocoThresholds(),
  Seq(JacocoReportFormats.XML),
  "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to do it:

```
lazy val jacoco = Seq(jacocoReportSettings in Test := 
JacocoReportSettings()
  .withTitle("MyProject")
  .withFormats(JacocoReportFormats.XML)
)
lazy val root = Projectid = "MyProject", base = file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

Hope it helps.